# How can I select table with :not() selector?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that has one paragraph and one table.

I want to change the `font-size` of the paragraph using the `:not()` selector.

I tried the following, but it failed to select table element with this selector.

```
div :not(table){font-size:5px;}/*not working*/

<div><p>....</p><table>....</table></div>
```

https://codepen.io/nur49/pen/eYBvOZG

Comment: Would it be possible to put your code into a runnable snippet that the community could use to help troubleshoot your issue?

Comment: Its best practice to not link to an external site with your code. Instead, [edit] your question, pasting all code [correctly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the child of the div that is not the table, so you can use the > selector on the div

```
div > :not(table)
```

Here's the snippet:

```css
body{
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #7df3e0;
      font-size: 24pt;
    }

div > :not(table){
      font-size: 5px;
      
}
```

```html
<div>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr class="trr">
          <th>Roll</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>GPA</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>Nur</th>
            <th>5.0</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>02</th>
            <th><a href="https://www.prothomalo.com">prothomalo</a></th>
            <th>5.0</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>03</th>
            <th>Nur</th>
            <th>5.0</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>04</th>
            <th>Nur</th>
            <th>5.0</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: That's strange as the snippet works. Could you show your updated code  by editing your question and we'll have another look. Maybe I misunderstood which element you want to select and which element you want to alter.

Answer (score 0):

This might helps you.

`div >*:not(table){font-size:5px;}`